# Javascript code to create a new sheet for each item in a list

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need to create a macro on GoogleSheets which will look different names in a list on a sheet named "Suppliers" and create a new sheet for each name. Each sheet needs to be a copy of a different sheet called "Data". Column A on the new sheet needs to be filtered by the name. Each sheet also needs to be named after the item in the list.

I have a functioning macro to create the sheet for each name independently but can't work out how to make this cycle through a list of names and automatically generate a new sheet for each name.

The code I am currently using is below:

```
function Supplier1() {
var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Data'), true);
spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().setName('Supplier1');
spreadsheet.getRange('A:L').activate();

spreadsheet.getRange('A:L').createFilter();
spreadsheet.getRange('A1').activate();
var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
.setHiddenValues(['', 'Supplier2', 'Supplier3', 'Supplier4','Supplier5'])
.build();

spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(1, 
criteria);
spreadsheet.getRange('G:G').activate();
spreadsheet.getRange('C1').activate();
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().sort(3, true);
spreadsheet.getRange('D1').activate();
spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getFilter().sort(4, true);

function hideRows() {
["Supplier1"].forEach(function (s) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
sheet.hide(sheet.getRange('B:B'))
sheet.getRange('B:B')
    .getValues()
    .forEach(function (r, i) {
        if (!r[0]) sheet.hideRows(i + 1)
    });
});
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've written two functions for you. `factory` reads the names of Suppliers from the 'Suppliers' sheet A column and for each name does the work in `doTheWork` function. I've ommiteed the hiding functionality as I don't know what it's doing. If current code works, can always add that later.

Store names in 'Suppliers' sheet column A and run the factory function.

```
function factory() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var supSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Suppliers');
  var supNames = supSheet.getRange(1, 1, supSheet.getLastRow(), 1).geValues();
  supNames = supNames.map(function(el) {
    return el[0];
  });

  supNames.forEach(function(name, i) {
    doTheWork(ss, name, i, supNames);
  });
}

function doTheWork(ss, name, i, allNames) {
  if (!name || name.length == 0) return;

  ss.getSheetByName('Data').activate();
  var nSheet = ss.duplicateActiveSheet();
  nSheet.setName(name);

  nSheet.getRange('A:L').activate();
  nSheet.getRange('A:L').createFilter();
  nSheet.getRange('A1').activate();

  var values = [''].concat(allNames);
  values.splice(i+1, 1);
  var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
    .setHiddenValues(values)
    .build();

  nSheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(1, criteria);

  nSheet.getRange('G:G').activate();
  nSheet.getRange('C1').activate();
  nSheet.getFilter().sort(3, true);

  nSheet.getRange('D1').activate();
  nSheet.getFilter().sort(4, true);
}
```

Comment: This is great, thank you so much! How would you filter Column A on the new sheet by the name? This is what I've added:        var criteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria( name);       but it isn't finding the name variable.

Comment: I'm getting the error "Cannot find method getVisibleValues(object)" - any other ideas? Really appreciate your help

Comment: New error of "Visible values are not currently supported. As an alternative specify a list of hidden values that excludes the values that should be visible". I was using     setHiddenValues(['', 'Supplier2', 'Supplier3', 'Supplier4','Supplier5'])"    before but I don't think this would work in this instance as I need to hide everything except for the selected Supplier name

Comment: "You can't create a filter in a sheet that already has a filter. (line 22, file "Suppliers 5")". Thank you so much for all your help trying to solve this!